# get result of a Query in cell to another query dont work

Tags: google-sheets

I have some trouble with my queries i have try so hard to get it work. but its seems that Query can only get data from cell that have only text in it. If i try to get data from ex. = funktion its dont work.

Exempel for my Querys.

**IN CELL B1**

```
=query('DATA-IN-All-stocks'!A:B ;"select A where B = '" & TEXT( A2;"") & "'" ;-1)
```

***RESULT*** = This generet IMNP

**IN CELL B2**

```
=QUERY('DATA-IMNP-Swedbank'!A:M;"select C,D where B = '"&B1&"' and C = 'Köp'" ;0)
```

***RESULT*** = This generet N/A  = dont find anny...

When i Change B1 and only typing in text IMNP i get the RESULT correctly

Comment: I get the same result off the problem with if i have TEXT  IMNP in D1  and in B1 typing =D1  i get N/A

Comment: Can you share a spreadsheet with an example? I cannot reproduce the issue.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/a/toit.se/spreadsheets/d/1k8QZQBYzjMo4MpITW5ERqVH7y7XVYGQoGxwqBc5tFZM/edit?usp=sharing

Here you go.

Comment: Can you make the spreadsheet publicly accessible please?

Comment: Done. i am sorry for that.

Answer (score 0):

If you check `=LEN(B1)` you will see it is 14.

This might be because the import has fixed width fields used to split between columns.

You can easily circumvent this in your application by wrapping `TRIM` around the formula creating the ticker within B1.

Comment: Thx alot for this help!.

I am glad to learn more about this and this fix my problem. I have sitting days now to try to find a answer to this.

Realy greatfull .

Comment: If this helped you please accept the answer, thanks.